# Gitlab CI/CD how to set a tag as a variable (to be defined by a user)

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm currently trying to setup a CICD Pipeline for my project.

I know it's not the actual purpose of the pipeline, but I'm trying to use it to run scripts (for deployments) on different machines, via different runners. The "user" should have the possibility to choose a runner (VM) without changing the gitlab-ci.yml.

I already tried to do it as below, to have an user input field when starting the Pipeline:

```
variables:
 RUNNER_INSTANCE_TAG:
      value: "shell"
      description: "Unique Tag to specify the runner on the module-specific machine"

job:
 stage: deploy
  tags:
    - $RUNNER_INSTANCE_TAG
  script:
```

and also tried to set it up in the Settings >> CICD >> Variables...

Answer (score 1):

You can predefine a variable and change it manually in the Pipeline you want to run. Run the pipeline manually as described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/index.html#run-a-pipeline-manually) and override the variables with the user input, the picture shows the screen in Gitlab UI:
[image: Run pipeline manually]
You can override as many variables as you want, care for Typos.

You could also use the URL features to simplify this, using [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/index.html#run-a-pipeline-by-using-a-url-query-string) reference.